# Counting the number of siblings a process has, Linux kernel

Tags: c, linked-list, linux-kernel

I'm using the `list_for_each` macro and the `sibling` field of the `current` `task_struct` to print out the number of siblings `current` has.

Here's the code (`inf.num_siblings` tracks the number of siblings):

```
    struct list_head *curr_node;
    ....
    list_for_each(curr_node, &(current->sibling)) {
                inf.num_siblings++;
            }
    ...
    //print inf.num_siblings
```

`current->sibling` points to a node in a circularly linked list, so I think the code above should count the number of siblings/node in said list correctly.

This code seems to mostly work. If I run a program in the background that just loops forever before running the "count siblings" code, then the number of siblings for the `current` process increases by one compared with the count that existed before I ran the loop code. However, if I run a process that calls `fork()` once before starting to loop, rather than seeing the sibling count increase by two as I would expect, it only increases by one. Why is that?

Here is the code that forks then loops:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    fork();

    while(1){
        sleep(3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `fork` you create a `child` process not a `sibling`. When you fork you'll increase the `current->children` count not the `current->sibling` count :)

Answer (score 0):

From: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html

When you called fork() the new process you created is a child and not a sibling of the process in which you called fork(). The sibling is correctly not getting incremented in this case.

Now, if you call fork() a bunch of times, and track the sibling count for the first child process, you will see the sibling count go up.